# How do I change the TF tensor to the Numpy array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

df['name']'s all elements are string

```
a = list(df['name'])

text_vectorization = TextVectorization(output_mode = "int",
                                       max_tokens=100,
                                       output_length=10)


my_li = []
for i in a:
  my_li.append(list(text_vectorization(i)))

my_li[0]
```

my_li[0] is

> [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=22>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=79>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=13>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=3>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=8>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=4>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=5>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=63>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=34>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=2>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=10>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=25>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=74>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=53>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=85>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=7>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=27>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=54>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=125>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=76>]

i need a numpy array of to learn by putting them in the model

I want to change "my_li" list to numpy array

Comment: Do you want to cast my_li[0] or my_li to a numpy array? In case you want to cast the whole list, you might have issues if list elements have different sizes. Standard numpy nd arrays should have fixed length

Comment: You can use `.numpy()` to convert any tensor to numpy array. Please try by using `my_li.numpy()` to get numpy array.